# Is there any way to get the owner of a YouTube video via the 3.0 api?

Tags: php, youtube-api, google-api-php-client

I'm looking for some sort of username or uid field associated with the video (so I can confirm that a video someone claims to own is really owned by that person).  I'd expect it to be in "snippet", but it's not there.  I guess I could go through the channels interface and the playlist of the user, but I'd think the video's owner is something that would be available through the videos api itself.  Any ideas?

Comment: To what will you compare the uid? Do you have that user's uid already?

Comment: Yes -- I can get that from a userinfo call once the user has logged in and created a valid access token.  (Assuming that these things line up, of course...)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**snippet** is correct, and the field is called "**channelTitle**"

Screenshot:
[image]

Comment: Hmm -- I'm not sure.  In my case, channelTitle is "Jim Miller" (spaces included), which probably comes from the way that I have either my Google or YouTube account set up.  I'm not sure that would be guaranteed to be unique across all users.  I think I'm still looking, but thanks!

Comment: If you want a unique identification across all users to call channel API later, you should check out "channelId" field. Example "channelId": "UCqRDbhIFsKOCKY-rnCNighA". "channelTitle" is only for user interface for user friendly.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, video owner is not returned from Videos resource.

- You can do [Channels->list](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/channels/list)
- from [relatedPlaylist.uploads](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/channels#contentDetails.relatedPlaylists.uploads).
- Iterate through [PlaylisItems](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/playlistItems/list) to match.

Answer (score 1):

Use [Channels.list](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/channels/list)

`snippet.channelTitle` will give you the name of the Channel.

`contentDetails.googlePlusUserId` might give you more info, but only if the user has associated a Google+ account with with the YouTube channel.

Make sure to specify `part='snippet,contentDetails'`

There is also a *lot* of information in:
http://www.youtube.com/get_video_info?video_id=*your-video-id*, including a field called `content_owner_name`. It requires some parsing to extract the info.